# When i am compiling it it shows a errors regarding Product.java. but that file is working and displayed

Tags: java, tomcat

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

public class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {

//List to hold Employees object
public HashMap<String,Product> prodList = null;

public Product product = null;

//getter method for employee list
public HashMap<String,Product> getEmpList() {
    return prodList;
}

boolean bImage = false;
boolean bName = false;
boolean bAccessories = false;
boolean bCondition = false;
boolean bPrice = false;

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
        throws SAXException {

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("watch" )) {
        //create a new Employee and put it in Map
        String id = attributes.getValue("id");
        //initialize Employee object and set id attribute
        product = new Product();
        product.setId(id);
        String retailer = attributes.getValue("retailer");
        //initialize Employee object and set id attribute
        product.setRetailer(retailer);
        product.setProducttype(qName);
        //initialize list
        if (prodList == null)
            prodList = new HashMap<String,Product>();
    } 
    else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("speaker" )) {
        //create a new Employee and put it in Map
        String id = attributes.getValue("id");
        //initialize Employee object and set id attribute
        product = new Product();
        product.setId(id);
        String retailer = attributes.getValue("retailer");
        //initialize Employee object and set id attribute
        product.setRetailer(retailer);
        product.setProducttype(qName);
        //initialize list
        if (prodList == null)
            prodList = new HashMap<String,Product>();
    } 
     else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("laptop" )) {
        //create a new Employee and put it in Map
        String id = attributes.getValue("id");
        //initialize Employee object and set id attribute
        product = new Product();
        product.setId(id);
        String retailer = attributes.getValue("retailer");
        //initialize Employee object and set id attribute
        product.setRetailer(retailer);
        product.setProducttype(qName);
        //initialize list
        if (prodList == null)
            prodList = new HashMap<String,Product>();
    } 
      else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("headphone" )) {
        //create a new Employee and put it in Map
        String id = attributes.getValue("id");
        //initialize Employee object and set id attribute
        product = new Product();
        product.setId(id);
        String retailer = attributes.getValue("retailer");
        //initialize Employee object and set id attribute
        product.setRetailer(retailer);
        product.setProducttype(qName);
        //initialize list
        if (prodList == null)
            prodList = new HashMap<String,Product>();
    } 
    else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("phone" )) {
        //create a new Employee and put it in Map
        String id = attributes.getValue("id");
        //initialize Employee object and set id attribute
        product = new Product();
        product.setId(id);
        String retailer = attributes.getValue("retailer");
        //initialize Employee object and set id attribute
        product.setRetailer(retailer);
        product.setProducttype(qName);
        //initialize list
        if (prodList == null)
            prodList = new HashMap<String,Product>();
    } 
       else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("storage" )) {
        //create a new Employee and put it in Map
        String id = attributes.getValue("id");
        //initialize Employee object and set id attribute
        product = new Product();
        product.setId(id);
        String retailer = attributes.getValue("retailer");
        //initialize Employee object and set id attribute
        product.setRetailer(retailer);
        product.setProducttype(qName);
        //initialize list
        if (prodList == null)
            prodList = new HashMap<String,Product>();
    }

    else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
        //set boolean values for fields, will be used in setting Employee variables
        bName = true;
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("image")) {
        bImage = true;
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("accessories")) {
        bAccessories = true;
    }else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("condition")) {
        bCondition = true;
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("price")) {
        bPrice = true;
    } 
     }

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("watch"))
            {
        //add Product object to list
        prodList.put(product.getId(),product);
    }
    else if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("speaker"))
            {
        //add Product object to list
        prodList.put(product.getId(),product);
            }
             else if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("laptop"))
            {
        //add Product object to list
        prodList.put(product.getId(),product);
            }
             else if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("headphone"))
            {
        //add Product object to list
        prodList.put(product.getId(),product);
            }
             else if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("phone"))
            {
        //add Product object to list
        prodList.put(product.getId(),product);
            }
             else if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("storage"))
            {
        //add Product object to list
        prodList.put(product.getId(),product);
            }
    }

@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    if (bImage) {
        //age element, set Employee age
        product.setImage(new String(ch, start, length));
        bImage = false;
    } else if (bName) {
        product.setName(new String(ch, start, length));
        bName = false;
    } else if (bCondition) {
        product.setCondition(new String(ch, start, length));
        bCondition = false;
    } else if (bPrice) {
        product.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(new String(ch, start, length)));
        bPrice = false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: it shows error ... could you be a wee bit more specific on that part?

Comment: MyHandler.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    public HashMap<String,Product> prodList = null;
                          ^
  symbol:   class Product
  location: class MyHandler
MyHandler.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
    public Product product = null;

Comment: put that in the question, not in a comment. otherwise people who want to help, 'll have to search all over the page just to know what the (entire) question is

Comment: Is your Product class in the same package as your MyHandler class ?

Comment: Yes. It is in the same package

Comment: I would definitely recommend cleaning up your code, removing duplicate code and such. you'll end up with a much shorter (and clearer) code

Comment: What o you mean by cleaning up the code. I am making a web application and using this class in my Sax Parser class. but it ain't accepting the MyHandler and Product class.

Comment: I mean you are writing a lot of duplicate code. that makes it way longer than it should be, and harder to maintain.

Comment: @Amit Do you have your own package or you are using the default one?

Comment: Welcome to Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: default one. and i have to do the longer code so that each and every functionalities gets managed.

Comment: And please: dont provide more infos in **comments**. Update your question instead. And before you post any other question: spend some serious time at [help] to learn how/what to ask here.

Comment: @Amit that is nonsense. whether you duplicate the code or not, the functionality would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Product` is not recognized as a type. It occurs because very likely `class Product` is not in the same package as `MyHandler` class. So there are two ways to deal with it:

1. Put `Product` class in the same package as `MyHandler` class is
2. Import the `Product` class. Let's say it's in `mypackage` package. Then you need to add:

   `import mypackage.Product;`

at the top of `MyHandler` class.

If the `Product` class **is** in the same package, e.x. `mypackage`, then you need to add this line at the top of your `MyHandler` class as well as in the `Product` class:

```
package mypackage;
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: he has already commented the classes are in the same package.

Comment: I know, that's why I deleted my answer. But then I noticed that he has not `package` line at the top of his class, so I undeleted it and updated. Maybe that's the case

Comment: or he's in the default package

Comment: I am in the default npackage

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at your import statements, there is no such class has been imported.So first import the Product class in MyHandeler.

Comment: read the comments. the class is in the same package, import is not needed.

Comment: Then He should have look at Access Modifiers for Product Class